# MQXR Load balancing

Tags: mqtt, load-balancing, ibm-mq, subscription, broker

Does MQXR support shared subscriptions.
We have an active/active pair of Integration Nodes, both of which subscribe to a topic. We need to load balance the publications but not duplicate them.
I cannot find any documentation to suggest that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM MQ currently does not support MQTT v5 features.  Shared subscriptions are part of MQTT v5.  IBM MQ only supports MQTT v3.1 and v3.1.1.

Comment: Thanks Roger. Not the answer I wanted but definitely the answer I needed.

Comment: Of course I can. My comment relates to the face that as we MUST use MQXR, your answer is invaluable. It would have been good if MQXR was capable, but as it's not, I need to develop a solution to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @KenMarshall I think you misunderstood me.  I meant "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."  Hence, I will get my points.

Comment: Apologies Roger - I'm a new contributor. All done.